# CSS class isn't accepted by React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Im stuck on a simple error, but just can't find it.

I have created an const, too style an element. Now I want to put the constant into the CSS, but somehow that doesn't work.

I want delete this line:

```
 <div style={OVERLAY_STYLES}/>
```

Can somebody explain my mistake?

```
const OVERLAY_STYLES = {
  position: "fixed",
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0, .7)",
  zIndex: 1000,
};



export default function Modal({ open, children, onClick }) {
  const [check, setCheck] = useState([]);

......

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <div className="OVERLAY_STYLES">
    <div style={OVERLAY_STYLES}/>
      <div className="MODAL_STYLES">
        <h1>Blabla.</h1>
        {attribute.map((att, index) => {
          return (
            <div>
              ......
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <div className="b01">
        <button onClick={() => onClick(check)} >Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    ,
    document.getElementById("portal")
  );
}
```

```
.OVERLAY_STYLES {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .7);
  z-index: 1000;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

In react inline styling, all values need to be inside ' ' . Change your `OVERLAY_STYLES` code to:

```
 .OVERLAY_STYLES {
  position: 'fixed';
  top: '0';
  left: '0';
  right: '0';
  bottom: '0';
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, .7)';
  z-index: '1000';
  };
```

also, no dashes so change `background-color` to `backgroundColor`

Comment: Are you sure? I have never seen it in ' ' in the CSS. But I give it a try, but it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, you only need them in the style const. In you don't need it in the css.

Comment: So my code is not working? This style is not applying?

Comment: The const works. But I want to delete it. I want to use only css-files to style my code.

Comment: Add class='OVERLAY_STYLES' to your elemnt insted of style={OVERLAY_STYLES}, and add the style to your css file

Answer (score 0):

### **Root Cause:-**

You are wrapping your `<div style={OVERLAY_STYLES}/>` under `<div className="OVERLAY_STYLES">`.
You are using the same style on both **div** tags which have `z-index` applied with the same value. So in your case:-  with inline-style is appearing above the parent div by hiding it under itself.

I am attaching the snippet have a look for the reference:-

```js
        const OVERLAY_STYLES = {
          position: "fixed",
          top: 20,
          left: 20,
          right: 20,
          bottom: 20,
          backgroundColor: "red",
          zIndex: 1000,
          color:"white",
          width:"50%",
        };

    const App = () => /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", {
  className: "OVERLAY_STYLES"
}, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", {
  style: OVERLAY_STYLES
}, "hELLO"));



    ReactDOM.render( /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(App, null), document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
    .OVERLAY_STYLES{
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: ;
          background-color: yellow;
          z-index: 1000;
          color:green;
          width:100vw;
          height:700px;
        };
```

```html
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


        <div id="app"></div>
```

### **Solution:-**

Try changing z-index/width.
**Note:-**Element with higher z-index will be at the top.

Comment: I think I am expressing myself incorrectly. My code works. Only I would like to delete the above line and not use a style. I just want to use the css file. Also the index is correct.